# Typesetting a matrix with crossing arrows on it

Tags: matrices

I'm able to draw matrices on LaTeX but I don't know how to put crossing arrows on it as the second matrix in the figure.

[image: Example of what I want]

I tried to make it 5 x 5 matrices and put `\diagup`, `\diagdown` on diagonals but it didn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also, a picture/mockup of what you want might be very helpfull.

Comment: My TikZ-sense is tingling

Comment: @Seamus: Your sense didn't fool you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I once worked out a similar thing with [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (surprise, surprise!) as a solution to a question where else.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \matrix [%
      matrix of math nodes,
      column sep=1em,
      row sep=1em
    ] (sarrus) {%
      a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
      a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{21} & a_{22} \\
      a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{31} & a_{32} \\
    };

    \path ($(sarrus-1-1.north west)-(0.5em,0)$) edge ($(sarrus-3-1.south west)-(0.5em,0)$)
          ($(sarrus-1-3.north east)+(0.5em,0)$) edge ($(sarrus-3-3.south east)+(0.5em,0)$)
          (sarrus-1-1)                          edge            (sarrus-2-2)
          (sarrus-2-2)                          edge[->]        (sarrus-3-3)
          (sarrus-1-2)                          edge            (sarrus-2-3)
          (sarrus-2-3)                          edge[->]        (sarrus-3-4)
          (sarrus-1-3)                          edge            (sarrus-2-4)
          (sarrus-2-4)                          edge[->]        (sarrus-3-5)
          (sarrus-3-1)                          edge[dashed]    (sarrus-2-2)
          (sarrus-2-2)                          edge[->,dashed] (sarrus-1-3)
          (sarrus-3-2)                          edge[dashed]    (sarrus-2-3)
          (sarrus-2-3)                          edge[->,dashed] (sarrus-1-4)
          (sarrus-3-3)                          edge[dashed]    (sarrus-2-4)
          (sarrus-2-4)                          edge[->,dashed] (sarrus-1-5);

    \foreach \c in {1,2,3} {\node[anchor=south] at (sarrus-1-\c.north) {$+$};};
    \foreach \c in {1,2,3} {\node[anchor=north] at (sarrus-3-\c.south) {$-$};};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you need help with further adaptations, feel free to ask.

---

[image]

Comment: +1 for the picture. I usually *don't* teach the Sarrus' rule.

Comment: Hi! there is a way to transforme your command in a 9-arguments math-command that we can call, for istance, '' \sarrus{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}{arg5}{arg6}{arg7}{arg8}{arg9} '' ? @Thorsten Donig

Comment: @egreg I want to reproduce the picture. I tried wit align. I want to write D=. Could you please help me? I tried ``\begin{align*}
D
& =  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth].....``but it does not work