# Arrows describing matrix

Tags: matrices, arrows, arrays

Lets say I have a 5x5 matrix.
I want to place 2 leftrightarrows (with descriptions "3", "2") underneath the matrix, but really close to it: first pointing from col1 to col3 and second from col4 to col5.
Plus updownarrows with similar outcome.
How can I achieve that?

draft:

1 1 1 | 1 1

<--> <->

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. - Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32981/124842, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40535/124842

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

matrix is drawn ... :-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix, quotes, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[LA/.style = {Straight Barb-Straight Barb,
                                 shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt,
                                 draw=red}
                    ]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             left  delimiter={[},
             right delimiter={]}
             ]
{
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
};
\draw (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-5-3.south east);
\draw (m-4-1.north west) -- (m-4-5.north east);
%
\draw[LA] (m-5-1.south west |- m.south) to ["3" '] (m-5-3.south east |- m.south);
\draw[LA] (m-5-4.south west |- m.south) to ["2" '] (m-5-5.south east |- m.south);
%
\coordinate[right=5mm of m.east] (e);
\draw[LA] (m-1-5.north east -| e) to ["3"] (m-3-5.south east -| e);
\draw[LA] (m-4-5.north east -| e) to ["2"] (m-5-5.south east -| e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You, it's exactly what I wanted :) But still I'm struggling with updownarrows on the right of matrix. Could you recomend me a book or script with documentation about matrix and arrows in tikz?

Comment: @Lucas, where should be this arrows? your question is not clear about this. i only figured out  these in my answer.

Comment: Outside of the matrix, on the right. Just like if You flip matrix from your answer 90 degrees counter clockwise.

Comment: Something like this, but with straight updownarrow: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340919/row-reduction-arrow-to-indicate-row-switch/340926 And I want to make 2 arrows, just like last time (values "3" and "2").

Comment: I wrote "Lets say I have a 5x5 matrix." at the begining of the question, but true, I should include sketch and I will.

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do with the latest version of `nicematrix` ( ≥ v. 6.22 2023-08-14).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-row = \color{red} ,
    code-for-last-col = \color{red} ,
    xdots/horizontal-labels
  }

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc|cc}[first-row,last-col,xdots/line-style=<->,margin=2pt]
\Hdotsfor{3}^{3} & \Hdotsfor{2}^{2} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \Vdotsfor{3}^{3}\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \Vdotsfor{2}^{2}\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Happy and prosper new year! I believe that v 5.8 if from this year: 20201? If so, you start to work in the very first day :-) ... (+1)

Comment: @Zarko: Yes, you are right. I will modify the date. Happy new year.