# Determinant with tikz latex

Tags: tikz-matrix

I need your help to formulate Sarrus rule for 3X3 matrix
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is already an answer of that sort [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32978/121799).

Comment: Thanks marmot. How to add the multiplication results (-4  0  6) at up and (0 16 -12) at down of matrix?

Comment: I *never* teach Sarrus' rule. It is handy, if you know it, in some cases; but students tend to use it also for larger matrices.

Comment: Off-topic. Is that a `3x3` matrix?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257043/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \edef\lstadd{{0,16,-12}}
 \edef\lstsub{{-4,0,6}}
 \matrix[matrix of math nodes,nodes={text width=1.5em}] (mat)
 {
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
    3 & -1 & 2 & 3 & -1\\
    4 & -4 & 1 & 4 & -4\\
 };
 \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+2)}]in {1,2,3}
 {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mylabel}{\lstadd[\X-1]}
 \draw[purple,-latex,thick] (mat-1-\X.north west) -- (mat-3-\Y.south east)
 node[pos=1.1]{\mylabel};
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mylabel}{\lstsub[\X-1]}
 \draw[purple,-latex,thick] (mat-3-\X.south west) -- (mat-1-\Y.north east)
 node[pos=1.1]{\mylabel};
 }
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \edef\lstadd{{0,16,-12}}
 \edef\lstsub{{-4,0,6}}
 \matrix[matrix of math nodes,nodes={text width=1.5em}] (mat)
 {
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
    3 & -1 & 2 & 3 & -1\\
    4 & -4 & 1 & 4 & -4\\
 };
 \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+2)}]in {1,2,3}
 {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mylabel}{\lstadd[\X-1]}
 \draw[purple,-latex,thick] (mat-1-\X.north west) -- (mat-3-\Y.south east)
 node[pos=1.1] (LL-\X) {\mylabel};
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mylabel}{\lstsub[\X-1]}
 \draw[purple,-latex,thick] (mat-3-\X.south west) -- (mat-1-\Y.north east)
 node[pos=1.1] (LU-\X) {\mylabel};
 }
 \draw[line width=1mm,purple,latex-,shorten >=1cm,shorten <=1cm]
 (LU-3.east) -- ++ (3,0) node[right] {Subtract these products};
 \draw[line width=1mm,purple,latex-,shorten >=1cm,shorten <=1cm]
 (LL-3.east-|LU-3.east) -- ++ (3,0) node[right] {Add these products};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]